# URL Rewriting based on form input

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I'm creating a frontpage for my website with a single form and input text, Google-style. It's working fine, however, I want to generate a pretty URL based on the input. Let's say, my input is called "id", and using the GET method of form, and the action defined to "/go/", on submission, the URL will be:

```
site.com/go/?id=whateverIType
```

and I want to change it to

```
site.com/go/whateverIType
```

I was thinking on Mod Rewrite, but if the user put something in the URL, like:

```
site.com/go/?dontwant=this&id=whateverIType&somemore=trash
```

I want to ignore the other variables but "id", and rewrite the rule.

What's the better way of get this done? Thanks in advance!

PS: I'm using CodeIgniter, maybe there's something I can use for it as well. I already have a controller for "go".

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with CodeIgniter, but you can try the following `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^\/go\/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([^&]*)
RewriteRule (.*) /go/%1? [L,R]
```

The `%1` references the regex group from the previous `RewriteCond`, and the trailing `?` will strip the querystring from the redirected URL.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The `?` character is a special character in RegEx. Are you sure you don't need to escape it ( `\?` )?

Comment: The second parameter of the `RewriteRule` is a string, so the `?` is OK.

Comment: I was thinking, and I will create a dedicated search controller accepting the data through GET request. Thanks anyway clmarquat!

Answer (score 2):

[Mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html) supports [conditions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond) and [rules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule) with RegEx, so you could have a rule that matched the `?id=XXXX`, that would extract it from the URL (keeping the other parameters), and rewrote the URL accordingly.

However... I don't think you want to do this, because if you rewrite the URL to be `/go/Some+Search+Query`, you won't be able to pick it up with say, PHP, without parsing the URL out manually.

It's really tough to have custom, SEO-friendly URLs with user input, but it is technically possible. You're better off leaving in the `?id=XXX` part, and instead, using mod_rewrite in the opposite approach... take all URLs that match the pattern `/go/My+Search+Terms` and translate that back into something like `?id=My+Search+Terms`, that way you'll be able to easily parse out the value using the URL's GET parameters. This isn't an uncommon practice - Google actually still uses URL parameters for user input (example URL: `http://www.google.com/search?q=test`).

Just keep in mind that mod_rewrite rewrites the URL before anything else (even PHP), so anything you do to the URL you need to handle. Think of mod_rewrite as a regular expression-based, global "Find and Replace" for URLs, every time a page is called on the server. For example, if you remove the query string, you need to make sure your website/application/whatever accounts for that.

Comment: Thanks for the advice SpikeX! In fact, I'm planning things backward! So, I have a better solution for my case: the form will create a GET request to a search controller. If it founds an exact match, then it will redirect to the product controller.

Answer (score 1):

In `application/config/routes.php`

```
$route['go/(:any)'] = "go/index/$1";
```

Where `go` is your controller and `index` is the index action.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

You can use something like this in your `.htaccess` if you aren't already:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Your solution solves the last part of the problem. For an exact result match, it will redirect the user to the correct controller. Thanks!